# RubyMine Terminal uses wrong RVM and no history in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rubymine

After updating RubyMine I've got working environment with right Settings and `rvm current` returned `2.2.4` version as expected. But Rails was running always under another version (`2.3.1`).

Answer (score 26):

The key thing is that after updating RubyMine, the Terminal starts opening without proper RVM initialization. All what is needed is:

change setting **Shell path: `/bin/bash` -> `/bin/bash --login`**

[image]